# Scala Define a generic class that only accepts case classes

Tags: scala, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo, scala-generics

When defining a generic class in Scala how can I ensure that the type parameter 'A' must be a case class?

```
class TypedCollection[A](name: String){}
```

Context:

I'm trying to define a generic 'TypedCollection' wrapper class to interact a reactivemongo JSONCollection as though it were a collection of case classes (similar to Typesafe Slick for relational databases).

The reason 'A' must be a case class is so it will automatically be given an 'unapply' method. This method is used in the generic class when creating the implicit conversions for type 'A' to a JsObject or BSONObject so it can be stored in MongoDB. i.e.

```
implicit val AWrites = Json.writes[A]

implicit val AReads = Json.reads[A]
```

Comment: Don't see the goal... why not checking there `A : OWrites`, or `A : OFormat` (or `A : BSONDocument{Reader,Writer}`) ?

Answer (score 1):

The most specific direct ancestor of all case classes (as well as tuples) is *Product*. It's not mentioned directly in scaladoc that it always provides companion object with *unapply* for his descendant, but in practice all subclasses (case classes and tuples) follow this convention. So, you can define bound on you type parameter like this:

```
class TypedCollection[A <: Product](name: String){}
```

Comment: How would you import Product, because Scala does not seem to know it?